# Through Verb+ing

Tags: adverbs

contribute to health care in an effective way through 'the delivery' of accurate diagnosis as well as 'increasing' our understanding of diseases.

Is this form acceptable? I know that you can write verb+ing after "through", but is it acceptable in this context?

Comment: Why do think it is incorrect to use 'verb + ing' after through in this sentence? "contribute to health care in an effective way through delivering accurate diagnoses as well as 'increasing' our understanding of diseases." seems fine to me

Comment: okay, so I should say delivering not 'the delivery'

Comment: by delivering x and by increasing y

Answer (score 1):

First, the *-ing* form is not normally used after *through* in this type of construction. It's normally used after *by* instead.

The only issue with the sentence as you have it is that **increasing** is read as coming after an implied **through**, which reads in a slightly awkward way.

This can be corrected:

> Contribute to health care in an effective way **through the delivery** of accurate diagnoses as well as **by increasing** our understanding of diseases.

(Note that I used the plural *diagnoses* as there will not just be one.)

Here, the use of **by** in front of *increasing* prevents the different verb form from sounding strange. The **by** makes it explicit that the second item should not be read as **through . . . increasing**.

---

Alternative, you can keep the implicit **through** if you wish:

> Contribute to health care in an effective way **through the delivery** of accurate diagnoses as well as **an increase in** our understanding of diseases.

Or you can use **by** instead:

> Contribute to health care in an effective way **by delivering** accurate diagnoses as well as **increasing** our understanding of diseases.

Comment: Your last one is the one I would use. But I might replace as well as by and.